# How can I modify card-colmns of bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I am using `card-columns` class from Bootstrap 4 to design a page for my portfolio. Everything is fine but I want a change in the look so that it looks some more attractive.

[image]

This is the design I have made. I want the **Other Projects** (same width as of **Latest Projects**) card to stay below **Latest Projects** so that the card below **Other Projects** (as per the current picture) stay on top of that column then **Skills**.

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">About Me</h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="card-text">
                <ul>
                    <li><b>Languages:</b> Python, JAVA, C</li>
                    <li><b>Frameworks:</b> Bootstrap (Frontend), Flask, Django, OpenCV</li>
                    <li><b>Database:</b> MySQL, MS SQL Server</li>
                    <li><b>Tools:</b> MySQL Workbench, Git</li>
                    <li><b>Editors Used:</b> Visual Studio Code, Sublime Text, Vim</li>
                    <li><b>Operating Systems:</b> Linux (Ubuntu), Windows</li>
                    <li><b>Total Experience: </b>Freshers</li>
                    <li><b>Current Employer: </b>Student</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card p-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">Latest Projects</h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="card-text">
                <h5 class="text-center">BT Real Estate</h5>
                <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='pic/btre.png')}}" alt="BTRE" class="btre">
                <label style="font-size: 10pt;">
                    <b>Technology Used: </b>HTM/CSS/JS(Frontend), Python-Django(Backend), Postgres SQL(Database)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='pic/rms.png')}}" class="card-img" alt="rms" height="150" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 style="font-size: 1.2rem;">Reminder Management System</h5>
                        <label style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>Technology Used: </b></label>
                        <label>HTML/CSS/JS(Frontend), Python-Flask(Backend), Postgres SQL(Database)</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card p-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">Other Projects</h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="card-text">
                <h5>Stock Management System</h5>
                <p>Manages stock of a company and it's distributor & outlet. Distributor can buy product from Company and Outlet can buy from Distributor.</p>
                <label><b>Technology Used: </b></label>
                <label>HTML/CSS/JS(Frontend), Python-Flask(Backend), Postgres SQL(Database)</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="max-width: 25rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-text">
                <ul>
                    <li class="contact"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Kolkata, West Bengal, India</li>
                    <li class="contact"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>avishek.arunavo1997@gmail.com</li>
                    <li class="contact"><i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>Download Resume</li>
                    <li class="contact"><i class="far fa-comments"></i>Contact Me</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
This is the template

.card-columns
{
    column-count: 2 !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    transform: translateY(10%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(10%);
}
```

This is the `card-columns` css which I had edited for making 2 columns.

It will be great if you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap features:

```
<div class="card p-3 col-12">
<div class="card-body">
<h3 class="card-title">Other Projects</h3>
```

...

```
</div>
</div>
```

to make section full width and move it below Latest Project.
So you can wrap "card-body" div with `col-6` if you want to have the section wider as the previous.

Here a complete list of bootstrap features you can use:
https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/

Comment: How can adding ```col-12``` benefit me to shift the card below the ```Latest Project``` card. As per ```card-columns``` I think the will make 12 columns with respect to the the column in which it is present

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at a basic bootstrap guide for understanding columns and rows concepts. [Bootstrap 4 Grid System](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp).

Comment: your answer didn't solved my question. I had tried it.